# How to add a delay between loops when playing a tone in AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

I have created a sample function, which will play a short-duration tone instantly, with the infinite loop. Here is the code:

```
let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
audioPlayer.play()
```

How to create a 5 second delay before the player will play the tone again? Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no simple way of doing this. You should use `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`. Please find some example below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate
{
    private var player: AVAudioPlayer!

    @objc private func startPlaying()
    {
         self.player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
         self.player.delegate = self
         self.player.play()
    }

    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool)
    {
         self.perform(#selector(startPlaying), with: nil, afterDelay: 5)
    }
}
```

Don't forget to stop selector whenever you want stop the continuation of the audio:

```
NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self)
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot!

Comment: A simple hack for some uses cases: create an N-second file that is mostly silence. Create an N-second file by adding silence to the MP3 using an editor such as Audacity. Loop that file forever (numberOfLoops = -1). This technique may only be useful for short intervals (1 or 2 seconds), if the processor is sporadically burdened by a heavy load, and if testing shows that using a timer yields intervals the user perceives as uneven. This hack could cause other complications, but may be worth the trouble for uniform intervals.